# Help with "schmecken" verb + dative

Tags: translation, verb

I'm a German newbie and I'm trying to translate

> "Der Wein schmeckt dem Mann"

Der Wein = the wine, subject
schmeckt = ? tastes ?
dem Mann = to the Mann

I can't give this sentence a meaningful translation, can someone help me out please?

Comment: The structure is the same as in „Der Wein gefällt dem Mann.“  Not sure if that is helpful, though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Schmecken` itself does not need to be determined more precisely, e. g. by an adverb.

If it is used alone, **it indicates something is tasty.**

> Die Birnen schmecken, aber die Äpfel nicht

This can be translated

> The pears taste good, but the apples do not.

Finally `dem Mann` is the indirect object saying to whom the wine tastes good.

> The mother dishes up and the boy says
>   "Das schmeckt mir nicht."